# receiving and returning methods

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a simple program that calls various methods that prompts the user for their city and state name and population than gives a percentage of the population. I've gotten most of the code down but I keep getting 1 compiler error that says

> "Error: cannot find symbol, variable: cityPercState"

can someone tell me whats wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CityOrozcoB52 
{ // begin class
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { // begin main method

    String city, state;
    float cityPopulation, statePopulation;



    cityName();
    stateName();
    cityPopulation(city);
    statePopulation(state);
    cityPercState(cityPopulation, statePopulation);
    displayCityStateStats(city, state, cityPopulation, statePopulation, cityPercState);



 } // end main method

  public static String cityName()
  {
    String city = "";
    System.out.printf("What is the name of your city:");
     city = input.nextLine();

     return city;
  }

  public static String stateName()
  {
    String state = "";
    System.out.printf("What is the name of your state:");
    state = input.nextLine();

    return state;
  }

  public static float cityPopulation(String city)
  {
    float cityPopulation = 0;
    System.out.printf("what is the population of %s:\n", city);
    cityPopulation = input.nextFloat();

    return cityPopulation; 
  }
  public static float statePopulation(String state)
  {
    float statePopulation = 0;
    System.out.printf("what is the population of %s:", state);
    statePopulation = input.nextFloat();

    return statePopulation;
  }

  public static float cityPercState(float cityPopulation, float statePopulation)
  {
   float cityStatePercentage = (cityPopulation / statePopulation) * 100; 
  }

  public static void displayCityStateStats(String cityName, String stateName, float cityPopulation, float statePopulation, 
                                      float cityPercState)
  {
   System.out.printf("POPULATION STATISTICS\n\n"
                    + "City: %s"
                    + "State: %s"
                    + "City Population: %f"
                    + "State Population: %f"
                    + "City to State Population: %.2f%%", cityName, stateName, cityPopulation, statePopulation, 
                                                          cityPercState);

  }
} // ends CityOrozcoLE52
```

Comment: You are returning `float cityStatePercentage` from the methond `cityPercState` so when you are printing from the `displayCityStateStats` method there is no `cityPercState` variable

Comment: `cityPercState` is a method and  you mentioned it as variable in your `printf` statement. It should be something like `cityPercState(arg1, arg2)` so that it will return `float` values which is also missing from method.

Comment: well, do you have a variable `cityPercState` declared in the scope you attempt to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually **return** a value in the `cityPercState()` method.

So add:

```
return cityStatePercentage;
```

to the method.